# Javascript sorting array

Tags: javascript, sorting

I am trying to write a sort function where the list should have the 1st item whose `type = 'text/xml'` but after that all items should be sorted by name ascending.

I will have just 2 types in my dataset: `text/xml` and `img/jpg`

Here is my code:

```
var fileArray = [
    {"name":'1101.jpg', type:"img/jpg"},
  {"name":'1301.jpg', type:"img/jpg"},
  {"name":'1001.jpg', type:"img/jpg"},
  {"name":'1005.jpg', type:"img/jpg"},
  {"name":'1201.jpg', type:"img/jpg"},
  {"name":'1500.jpg', type:"img/jpg"},
  {"name":'MyFile.xml', type:"text/xml"}, 
  {"name":'1700.jpg', type:"img/jpg"},
 ];

 fileArray.sort(function (a, b) { return b.type >= a.type });

        fileArray.sort(function (a, b) {
            if (a.type == 'text/xml') {
                return -1000;
            }
            else {
                var rc = 0;
                var c = a.name;
                var d = b.name;
                if (c < d)
                    rc = -1;
                if (c > d)
                    rc = 1;
                return rc;
            }
        });

console.log(fileArray);
```

Here is my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mofuqada/1/

It seems to work with the sample data. However, wanted to ask if you see any issue in the code where it might not work with 100's of files

Comment: i think it works fine :)

Comment: I am using a double sort first on type and then by name. Is there any way I can remove the 1st sort of b.type >= a.type?

Comment: Yeah, it'll be fine. Sorting works on 2 items at a time, so it doesn't care how big the whole array is.

You can remove the `else` code and replace it with that check from the first sort. Then remove the first sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a check and use it as a value for sorting.

```
(a.type !== 'text/xml') - (b.type !== 'text/xml')
```

This part can be splitted into

```
a.type !== 'text/xml'
```

for `a` and for `b`

It is a simple check for unequality and return a boolean value like `true` or `false`. In the case for `'text/xml'` `false` and otherwise `true`.

But I need numerical values and `'text/xml'` must comes with a smaller value than other strings. So it does with conversion of `false` to `0` and `true` to `1`. The difference is the value for sorting.

Later the name is only compared if the previous calculation is falsy, `0` in this case.

```js
var fileArray = [{ name: '1101.jpg', type: "img/jpg" }, { name: '1301.jpg', type: "img/jpg" }, { name: '1001.jpg', type: "img/jpg" }, { name: '1005.jpg', type: "img/jpg" }, { name: '1201.jpg', type: "img/jpg" }, { name: '1500.jpg', type: "img/jpg" }, { name: 'MyFile.xml', type: "text/xml" }, { name: '1700.jpg', type: "img/jpg" }];

fileArray.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (a.type !== 'text/xml') - (b.type !== 'text/xml') || a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
});

console.log(fileArray);
```

Comment: Thank you but the output doesn't look. text/xml should be the 1st file regardless and then the other items need to be sorted.

Comment: It doesn't. Does it for you?

Comment: It doesn't for me as well.

Comment: This is what the output is for me: **[
  {
    "name": "1001.jpg",
    "type": "img/jpg"
  },
  {
    "name": "1005.jpg",
    "type": "img/jpg"
  },
  {
    "name": "1101.jpg",
    "type": "img/jpg"
  },
  {
    "name": "1201.jpg",
    "type": "img/jpg"
  },
  {
    "name": "1301.jpg",
    "type": "img/jpg"
  },
  {
    "name": "1500.jpg",
    "type": "img/jpg"
  },
  {
    "name": "MyFile.xml",
    "type": "text/xml"
  },
  {
    "name": "1700.jpg",
    "type": "img/jpg"
  }
]**

Comment: Short and sweet. Seems to work now. What did you change?

Comment: Also please explain what does (a.type !== 'text/xml') - (b.type !== 'text/xml') actually do?

Comment: i has a space in the strin in this part `(b.type !== 'text/xml#')` where the hash is now. you can see it in the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38502757/revisions)

Comment: Simply amazing explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an arithmetic based Rank calculator which can be then used to sort:

Note I have assumed that if there are multiple files with `text/xml` then they should be sorted by name as well. I have added an extra object with filename `File.xml` to depict the same.

#### Sample

```js
var fileArray=[{name:"1101.jpg",type:"img/jpg"},{name:"1301.jpg",type:"img/jpg"},{name:"1001.jpg",type:"img/jpg"},{name:"1005.jpg",type:"img/jpg"},{name:"1201.jpg",type:"img/jpg"},{name:"1500.jpg",type:"img/jpg"},{name:"MyFile.xml",type:"text/xml"},{name:"File.xml",type:"text/xml"},{name:"1700.jpg",type:"img/jpg"}];

fileArray.sort(function(a,b){
  var fileRank = a.type === b.type? 0 : a.type === "text/xml" ? -10 : 10;
  return (a.name > b.name ? 1: a.name < b.name ? -1 : 0) + fileRank;
})
  
console.log(fileArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
fileArray.sort(function(a,b){
    return a.name > b.name;
 }).sort(function(a,b){
    return a.type < b.type;
});
```

enjoy